# functions pca and princomp give different answers

Tags: matlab

My understanding is that princomp and pca are the same functions in MATLAB. But using these functions is giving different answers. The output below shows this:

```
>> size(pcainput)

ans =

29    50    

>> size(pca(pcainput))

ans =

50    28

>> size(princomp(pcainput))

ans =

50    50
```

Based on this output, it looks like the princomp is working as expected (a p x p coefficient matrix is generated), whereas pca appears to give a wrong answer. Is there a default setting or something that I have messed up? Looking in the code I can't figure out why I'm getting different answers with what appear to be identical functions.

Comment: What does `which pca` return?

Comment: While I don't see it stated anywhere that the two functions are identical (since they're not), but in R2012b indeed the corresponding helps say that the first output should be of size `p x p` if the input is of size `n x p`...

Comment: @Daniel, `which pca` returns `/Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/toolbox/stats/stats/pca.m`. I don't think I have moved anything, atleast not that I know of.

Comment: OK, we're back to the usual question. You have less rows than columns, i.e. less observations than variables. Does it make sense to do a PCA in this case?

Comment: The return of which is correct, just wanted to make sure there is nothing else called pca on your search path.